# Query database with conditions on negative longitude

Tags: php, sql, google-maps, geolocation, latitude-longitude

Small problem about Google Maps and storing/retrieving coordinates. I run a DB on MySql where I store longitude/latitudes of points in 2 separate float fields. I would like to perform queries to find the points fitting the bounds of a given google map object.

I get the min/max lng/lat from the current google map and perform a query through PHP. Everything works fine, except when I have negative values for the longitude. Which doesn't return any result whilst values fitting the min/max lng exist... My query looks like this:

```
SELECT * FROM points WHERE ((lng BETWEEN :lng_min AND :lng_max) AND (lat BETWEEN :lat_min AND :lat_max))
```

I checked each single variable sent to the query / stored in the database and each one is a valid float. This doesn't seem to make any sense. Am I missing something?

Comment: What are the colons for? Cant you skip them?

Comment: Using PDO? Your DB logging the queries? I'd check and make sure the query being ran is what you expect. Try running what you think is being sent as the query to the database and see if the result is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

An issue here is where in your query a negative value causes problems. For instance, if lng_min < 0 and lng_max >0, then you should be retrieving data as usually. However, if lng_max<0 and lng_min>0 (it can happen, as the earth is round and transitioning from -180 degrees to +180 degrees longitude is only a few footsteps away), then it makes sense for the database not to retrieve any values at all. If the latter is the case, then you should previously check if lng_max <0 and lng_min>0 and make an origin shift (e.g. (a+180) % 360) for all longitudes in the query. In any case, a few examples of lng_min/lng_max pairs  where the query fails would be helpful.